# Custom Warning annotation on Overridden method IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, annotations

In my project I have a base method that I do not want users to override. I am however not able to make this method final or private because I am using mockito to verify that the method is called for testing and we are not able to use power mock in the project. Is there a way to make a custom annotation that warns other developers if they attempt to override a said method? Code example below:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity {
    public void superOnResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public  void superOnPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

} 

public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
           superOnPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
           superOnResume();
    }

    //Warning annotation needed here!
    public void superOnPause(){
      super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Fake test example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ChildActivityTest {

    ChildActivity childActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        childActivity = spy(new ChildActivity());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnPause() {
        doNothing().when(childActivity).superOnPause();
        childActivity.onPause();
        verify(childActivity).superOnPause();
}
```

The following code allows me to test onResume/Pause methods in an activity. The issue is that there are a lot of classes extending the baseActivity. If someone accidentally created/overrides super OnPause/onResume it will call an infinite loop at run time.

Comment: "I am however not able to make this method final or private"  Howz this possible? If your base class can have a method, why you are not able to make it private / final? Or is it your business logic which prevents to do so ?

Comment: @Stallion I updated my question with more info.

Comment: May be `@Deprecated`?